# Arabic string with parameters invalid format

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, localization, android-resources

I have some arabic text in the app that has parameters.

```
<string name="text_1">s$1% نقطة إلى  s%2$</string>
```

The problem is that IDE shows an error when I am using this string

```
Format string text_1 is not a valid format string so it should not be passed to String.format
```

For english I have

```
   <string name="text_1"> %1$s beans to %2$s</string>
```

which is working just fine.

edit:

[image]

So, 1,3 & 4 are working just fine, the problem is with 2

How i need to format my arabic parameters to be ok?

Comment: You have to use the same string format no matter what language file you're creating. (See the Android Developer docs for more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling)

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the way you've defined the string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983711/android-handling-integer-1d-and-string-1s-arguments-for-right-to-left-l?rq=1

Comment: i am  using the same format s$1% for other strings and they work fine

Comment: Did you try inputting the inverted version of the formatter string?

Comment: @Edric i have edit the question

Answer (score 1):

I just copied your code and it works fine. 
[image]

Try to:

- clean the project
- check multi-language files
- or just use the string.format

This question was answered here with a similar issue:

[Format string XXX is not a valid format string so it should not be passed to String.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765890/format-string-xxx-is-not-a-valid-format-string-so-it-should-not-be-passed-to-str/51109685)

Comment: This is because OP is actually using an invalid format of defining a format string, not because of possible build problems: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling

Answer (score -2):

Also when using Arabic text, you should use

> %1$s and %2$s

not

> s$1% and s%2$